Regex c# pattern
I make a string pattern in c# is
(?:^|\/|-(?!tg|tog))(\w+-)?(tg|tog)(\d+)(?:$|#|\?)

where it work on as my expected
/path/name-tg1 : output: group[2]=tg, group[3]=1
/path/tog2 : output: group[2]=tog, group[3]=2
/tg3 : output: group[2]=tg, group[3]=3
/nametog2 : output: not match

right now I want to modify the pattern where expect
-tog4 : output: group[2]=tog, group[3]=4
/path#/tog4 : output: not match
/pa$th/tog4 : output: not match
/path./tog4 : output: not match
/p?ath/tog4 : output: not match
/#tg4 : output: not match

that mean enforce only allow character [a-z] or [0..9] or '/' or '-' or '_' before keyword "tg" or "tog"
can I know how to modify the above regex pattern

I think regex is a lot of overkill and really slow for the task that you want

Please explain what you want instead of letting us infer it from lots of examples. It is really hard to infer all the rules from examples.

You might use
^(?:[\w/]*/)?(\w*-)?(to?g)(\d+)$

The pattern matches:

^ Start of string
(?:[\w/]*/)? Optionally match word chars or / and then match /
(\w*-)? Optionally capture optional word chars followed by - in group 1
(to?g) Capture group 2, match tg or tog
(\d+) Capture group 3, match 1+ digits
$ End of string

Regex demo
Or perhaps another option to either start the string with - OR / and then optional repetitions of chars a-z followed by /
^(?:-|/(?:[a-z]+/)*)(\w+-)?(to?g)(\d+)$

Regex demo

It looks like a solution. Please also explain your regex.

@ArvindKumarAvinash I added a breakdown of the pattern.

@Thefourthbird if [a-z] is only allow a-z, can I can \S but exclude character with $,#, .
how to modified , but some of input value is encode url, like 20% and I don' want to too much complicate checking or decode url and check

@CarrieKaski Instead of [a-z] you could use ^(?:-|/(?:[^\s$#.?]+/)*)(\w+-)?(to?g)(\d+)$ see https://regex101.com/r/CVCwRn/1

Try this:
(^[a-z0-9\/\-_]+)(tg|tog)(\d+)$

The first pair of parentheses is not necessary, but it makes so your expected result goes to group 2 and 3.

Although your questions seems ambiguous but i think you are looking for this
^[a-z0-9\/\-_]+(?:tg|tog)|(\d+)$

if we take your statement " enforce only allow character [a-z] or [0..9] or '/' or '-' or '_' before keyword "tg" or "tog""

it's not work, when I type:
/path/tog2 , group[1] is 2. but there have no other group tog
and also then I type /pathtog2 , I expected not match, but I have return value
